# Remove Type form Apache apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava in generated source

Tags: apache, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java, auto-generate

I am trying to consume a WSDL, generate source form WSDL and XSDs in gradle using `org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava`. It generates classname as it is in XSDs and WSDL, but I want change all the generated class names in similar way. I know I can add binding file to it, but I would need to have entry for every element in the WSDL. 
Please help me with a generic for all the properties.

e.g XSD below :

```
<xs:complexType name="SomeType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SomeType2" type="CommonNS:Some2Type"/>
            <xs:element name="SomeType3" type="CommonNS:Some3Type" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

The classes generated are :

```
com.something.SomeType
com.something.Some2Type
com.something.Some3Type
```

But I want to generate it as :

```
com.something.Some
com.something.Some2
com.something.Some3
```